# How to enforce maximum line length for comments in VS + ReSharper?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, resharper, resharper-8.0, resharper-8.1

I've configured a maximum line length of 160 in ReSharper and code is formatted fine. However, comments are not formatted, they can be longer than 160 characters. Is there a way to format comments as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can format comments using the free CodeMaid Extension (Tools->Extensions and Updates), which integrates nicely with ReSharper.